# Ctypes convert var to float when i use .value

Tags: python, ctypes

I use that code to normalize my Structure vars, but when i call .value its convert original var(without value its c_float) to float.

```
class CVector(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("fX", c_float),
        ("fY", c_float),
        ("fZ", c_float)
    ]

    def __init__(self, fX, fY, fZ):
        super(CVector, self).__init__(fX, fY, fZ)

    def Normalize(self):
        # AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'value'
        self.t = sqrt(self.fX.value * self.fX.value  + self.fY.value * self.fY.value + self.fZ.value * self.fZ.value)

        return self.t
```

```
class CVector(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("fX", c_float),
        ("fY", c_float),
        ("fZ", c_float)
    ]

    def __init__(self, fX, fY, fZ):
        super(CVector, self).__init__(fX, fY, fZ)

    def Normalize(self):
        # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'c_float' and 'c_float'
        self.t = sqrt(self.fX * self.fX  + self.fY * self.fY + self.fZ * self.fZ)

        return self.t
```

Comment: Please `print(self.fX, self.fY, self.fZ)`…?

Comment: @deceze print in start of def Normalize out: `1.0 0.0 0.0`. I create this with `CVector(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)`

Comment: What I'm driving at is that not _all_ your values may be floats or `c_float`s at that point…?! If some of the values are `float`s and others `c_float`s, that would explain the behaviour perfectly…

Comment: I found problem with this code in Normalize ```CVector.fX = c_float(self.fX)
            CVector.fY = c_float(self.fY)
            CVector.fZ = c_float(self.fZ)```

But, without this, my Structure fields is float, not c_float

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75604593/edit) new code into the question, not a comment.  It's best to make a [mcve] that clearly reproduces the problem with no changes, such as including all imports and the code to generate the error, not just the class definition.

Comment: You're constructing the CVector with float values, how did you expect them to get converted to c_float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ctypes convert var to float when i use .value

That's what `.value` does...return the Python value for a `ctypes` type.

`def __init__: ...` is not needed.  The default `__init__` initializes the structure.

`.value` is not needed.  `Structure` uses `_fields_` to create attributes that convert the underlying managed C structure memory to the corresponding Python value for the field.

Below is working code, and an extra display function:

```py
import ctypes as ct
import math

class CVector(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("fX", ct.c_float),
                ("fY", ct.c_float),
                ("fZ", ct.c_float))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'CVector(fX={self.fX}, fY={self.fY}, fZ={self.fZ})'

    def normalize(self):
        self.t = sqrt(self.fX * self.fX  + self.fY * self.fY + self.fZ * self.fZ)
        return self.t

v = CVector(1, 0, 0)
print(v)
print(v.normalize())
v = CVector(2,3,4)
print(v)
print(v.normalize())
```

Output:

```
CVector(fX=1.0, fY=0.0, fZ=0.0)
1.0
CVector(fX=2.0, fY=3.0, fZ=4.0)
5.385164807134504
```